# Why image from JSON is not rendered in image tag in react native?

Tags: json, react-native, react-native-image

I have a json file

```
{
        "name": "SAM",
        "id": "001",
        "default_image":"../assets/image.jpeg"
}
```

In my component, I set a state called profile_image with this data called default_image, but when I use it like this, it throws an error.

```
<Image 
    style={styles.image} 
    source={{uri: this.state.profile_image}}/>
```

I have given width and height but still it throws an error. I have even tried all these possible formats but no success.

```
<Image 
    style={styles.image} 
    source={{this.state.profile_image}}/>

<Image 
    style={styles.image} 
    source={require(this.state.profile_image)}/>
```

Comment: `let a = this.state.profile_image`   and `source={require(a.default_image)}`

Comment: try to alert the path for the image and check whether you are getting the image or not?

Comment: Moreover, mention the error in the question. I am sure it will not be the syntax error..

Answer (score 0):

When using uri to display the image it is displayed using this:

```
<Image style={{width:120, height:80,  marginTop:15,alignSelf:'center'}}
source={{uri: this.state.avatarSource}}/>
```

So, you are not making any syntax error here.

The problem is with the path of the image you are giving from JSON

Try changing your JSON to this:

```
{
        "name": "SAM",
        "id": "001",
        "default_image":"/assets/image.jpeg"
}
```